# Search for Image class that contains specific text in jsoup

Tags: java, android, parsing, jsoup

If I had the following images inside of a div how would I be able to do a jsoup query that only returns the images that have the class that CONTAINS the text "absmiddle"?

```
<div>
       <img class="absmiddle-blah foo-bar" src="google.com/image.png" \>
       <img class="absmiddle-blah2 foo-bar2" src="google.com/image.png" \>
       <img class="ablehe-bla2h foo-bar3" src="google.com/image.png" \>
       <img class="absmiddle-bl2ah foo-bar4" src="google.com/image.png" \>
       <img class="blah-bl2ah foo-bar4" src="google.com/image.png" \>
       <img class="absmiddle-bl2ah foo-bar4" src="google.com/image.png" \>
       <img class="sdfdle-bl2ah foo-bar4" src="google.com/image.png" \>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String html =   "<div>"+
                               "<img class=\"absmiddle-blah foo-bar\" src=\"google.com/image.png\" \\>"+
                               "<img class=\"absmiddle-blah2 foo-bar2\" src=\"google.com/image.png\" \\>"+
                               "<img class=\"ablehe-bla2h foo-bar3\" src=\"google.com/image.png\" \\>"+
                               "<img class=\"absmiddle-bl2ah foo-bar4\" src=\"google.com/image.png\" \\>"+
                               "<img class=\"blah-bl2ah foo-bar4\" src=\"google.com/image.png\" \\>"+
                               "<img class=\"absmiddle-bl2ah foo-bar4\" src=\"google.com/image.png\" \\>"+
                               "<img class=\"sdfdle-bl2ah foo-bar4\" src=\"google.com/image.png\" \\>"+
                        "</div>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        Elements els = doc.select("img[class*=absmiddle]");
        System.out.println(els);
    }
}
```

You can check [here](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) for more examples of Jsoup's capabilities

Comment: How did you figure out about "*=" from the example you listed?  I knew about their example Jsoup page, but it didn't really give me any ideas about what you listed.  How did you find out about that? is there another site with more examples or something you got that from?

Comment: I've put a link to the documentation at the bottom of my answer. Check the section `Selector overview`. There you will find a bullet that mentions this : `[attr^=value], [attr$=value], [attr*=value]: elements with attributes that start with, end with, or contain the value`. Add to that the section `Selector combinations`, the bullet `el[attr]: elements with attribute, e.g. a[href]`

Comment: AH i saw that page, but apparently I just overlooked your example.  Thanks for being more clear!